# Twitter dialogflow open source integration

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have followed the steps given for integrating with the twitter https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations and everything was done as such and deployment was successfull but I didnt get the response back from the bot.I tried integrating with the same app using the older method of integration and it is working. How can I know what is the problem with the integration?I tried integrating with the same app using the older method of integration and it is working

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had the same issue. When deploying using `gcloud beta run deploy ...` command it tries to register new webhook on Twitter. In most cases it fails (eg. with `High latency on CRC GET request. Your webhook should respond in less than 3 seconds.` error). It is possible, that webhook registration will succeed after some deployments, but better approach would be to use local instance of [Twitter Activity Dashboard](https://github.com/twitterdev/account-activity-dashboard) - you can use targetUrl there and register webhook yourself (it’s possible that you will have to try several times). Remember to also verify it later with Verify button.
I have disabled Twitter integration in Dialogflow and my bot is now using Cloud Run webhook for Twitter.

Information in [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/issues/13) issue were very helpful.